# Cantor and infinities

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

Hello I was wondering if anyone can recommend any books in which would increase my knowledge to do with cantor sets and ordinals and cardinals and infinity , this is because my undergraduate project has the title infinities and there is no reading list on the title, thank you for taking time to read this

Comment: What kind of knowledge you are seeking? Do you want historical books about Cantor i.e. information how Cantor came up with the ideas or a more modern reference? And are you interested in philosophical aspects or are you more into the mathematics?

Comment: I'm more interested in the mathematics that he elaborated on and the same with dedekind one in which I would be able to learn the mathematics however I'm also interested in his life and the reactions from fellow mathematicians at the time

Comment: Most basic books with introduction and set theory in their title should do.

Comment: There are few books written about Cantor that I can recommend. One that comes to my mind immediately is from J.W. Dauben: "Georg Cantor: His Mathematics and Philosophy of the Infinite". It's a historical biography that also takes some mathematical details into account (you could at least be interested in some parts of it). Also the original letters between Dedekind and Cantor are available in English in Evans: "From Frege to Gödel vol II". There are also some of the Cantor's original articles translated in Evans.

Comment: However for more the mathematical stuff as Asaf pointed out, almost any book with introduction to set theory will do. Also the books that include basic measure theory almost surely have thing or two about Cantor set. You could try J. Stillwell: "The Real Numbers: An Introduction to Set Theory and Analysis".

Comment: Brilliant thank you, I've already got a book about classic set theory by derek goldrei but I don't think it goes into enough detail & I will be sure to have a look at your suggestions especially the letters between the two

Comment: Well the letters don't go too much on the details. They are mainly interesting from philosophical and historical point of view. Still it doesn't take too long to read them trough.

Comment: https://ests.files.wordpress.com/2016/01/note1.pdf